# add calculated column using pandas based on values in other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need help with adding Col4 based on data from Col1,2 and Col3. If Col3 has same values for all corresponding values in Col1/Col2, Col4 should read as "YES" otherwise "NO".

[[image: Data]]

[[image: ExpectedResult_Col4]]

Comment: One friend advice [Don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: kind of new to these :(

Comment: only pass data in text with 4 spaces before, if problem with formatting I can help with it after text data are passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with count number of unique values and compare by `1`, set new values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Col3'].transform('nunique') == 1
df['Col4'] = np.where(mask, 'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: i clicked the up arrow on your answer... is there anything else I need to do to accept answer?